# How to present user friendly message when API request setTimeout is exceeded?

Tags: apex, api

I am performing a call from Salesforce to the DWH. Rarely, I would exceed the 120000 time limit, but when we do, the user would be presented with a default apex error. I would like to capture that and instead present them with a user friendly error. I am not sure how I can capture that event. How can I say if time limit is exceeded then show an error.

```
Http http = new Http();
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
request.setTimeout(30000);//30000
request.setEndpoint('https://testURL');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a try-catch block to check for this condition:

```
try {
  new http().send(req);
  ...
} catch(CalloutException e) {
  ApexPages.addMessage(
    new ApexPages.Message(
      ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,
      'An exception occurred calling the API: '+e.getMessage()
    )
  );
}
```

Comment: Can't you just `ApexPages.addMessages(e)`?

Comment: @AdrianLarson Yeah, I just totally spaced that method.